# Does ClearCase tool provide Java api support?

Tags: java, rest, clearcase

I've requirement to connect to IBM rational ClearCase using java.

I need to perform all the operation  on clear case, such as checkin and checkout etc.

Do you have an example of such implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the [ClearCase CM API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474), see its [man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.team_api.doc/topics/c_introduction.htm):

> The IBM Rational® CCRC WAN server API is a unified Java™ API through which you can access ClearCase®. The ClearCase CM server API extends the WVCM (Workspace Versioning and Configuration Management) API, which is a standard Java API for configuration management (see "[JSR 147: Workspace Versioning and Configuration Management](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=147)").
>
> You can use the ClearCase CM API to build client applications that access Rational ClearCase and to build new integrations. The client application can be an Eclipse plugin or other Java client application. For example, you can use the API to build client applications that:
>
> - Perform ClearCase checkout and checkin operations from your Java application.
> - Browse the contents of a ClearCase web view or dynamic view on your local machine (snapshot views are not supported).
> - Create and modify ClearCase UCM objects, such as activities and streams.

You can see [new features introduced with ClearCase 8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474).

Note that it is more for a CCRC 7 / ClearTeam 8 environment than a regular ClearCase 7 server.

That means with ClearCase 7.1, you can use java clases wrapping `cleartool` (no REST API there...), as with "[Apache Ant ClearCase Tasks](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/clearcase.html)".
[CCCheckout](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/clearcase.html#cccheckout) would allows  to perform a "`cleartool checkout`" command to ClearCase.

Comment: My Clear case version is 7.1.2.4, what is this CM API is actually, is it to invoke commandline of clear tool or directly access clear case.. using some rest api calls?

Comment: @prathapdudvat no rest api call. For an old ClearCase 7.1, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3776095/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24184916/6309: the old java api would only work with a CCRC, not a classic ClearCase server.

Comment: @prathapdudvat I have edited the answer: that means Ant task for you (if you don't have a CCRC server)